# input from file Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы, input

Ребят, подскажите, пожалуйста, как считывать множественные переменные из файла?
Структура файла типа: несколько строк (каждая строка - отдельный набор вводимых данных), на каждой строке просто набор чисел, разделённых пробелами (чтобы отделить каждый input).

Например:

11 22 33

44 55 66

77 88 99

Необходимо считать с файла: a,b,c = 11,22,33.

Затем выполянется код с этими данными и переходит к следующей строке для получения новых данных и повторного выполнения.

Для начала я подгружаю файл f = open('file', 'r+')

Затем начинаю построчно читать f.readline(), но у меня интерпретатор выдает только <_io.TextIOWrapper name='inputs.rtf' mode='r+' encoding='US-ASCII'>
Спасибо.

Comment: если бы мы знали как вы хотите использовать прочитанные данные то могли бы дать более дельные советы... Например если вам надо производить подсчеты/расчеты, то очень удобно воспользоваться Numpy/Scipy/Pandas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот небольшой пример:

```
# Открытие файла
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    # Считывание всех строк
    for line in f.readlines():
        # Проверка на пустую строку
        line = line.strip()
        if not line:
            continue
        
        # Разбиение строки по пробелу и приведение ее частей к int
        a, b, c = map(int, line.split(' '))
        print('{} + {} + {} = {}'.format(a, b, c, (a + b + c)))
```

---

file.txt

```
12 33 11
12 3 1
1 3 11
```

Консоль:

```
12 + 33 + 11 = 56
12 + 3 + 1 = 16
1 + 3 + 11 = 15
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот вам решение почти в 1 строку:)

```
for a, b, c in map(lambda line: map(int, line.split()), filter(lambda line: line, map(lambda line: line.strip(), open(FILENAME)))):
   print(a, b, c)
```

Comment: for a, b, c in (list(map(int, line.split())) for line in open('file.txt') if line.strip()):
    print(a, b, c)